# asp mvc image reference from resx

Tags: asp.net-mvc, resx

I have ASP MVC 4 website.
I use ResX files to localize the site to different languages.
In one of my pages I display localized HTML content (case study) that has images in it.
The whole localized content is stored in a file and the ResX file reference it. This works great.

The problem is how to reference the images from within the localized content?
The images are stored in ~/Content/Img1.jpg (and so on).

For now I've simply put /Content/Img1.jpg but this will not work so good if the website will be deploy to a sub-directory and not the root domain.

Thank you,
Ido.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you give the same name to the pictures, and this pictures are already embedded in the resources, then you don't have to do anything else, just change the Culture and UICulture as always. If they are different then you might want to see the exact name by inspecting the resources file after compilation. And if your content always references the same static images, it shouldn't be a problem to put the normal path as you always do. The reference that starts with ~ will always start from the root and the structure can be ~Content/en-US/picture1.jpg for example. Let me know if it helps,

Comment: The tilda ~ sign does not work because inside the cshtml page (razor view) I put @Html.Raw(MyResource.Story) where Story point to the localized HTML file. This means I'll just get the ~/content/img.jpg without ASP framework do it magic to convert ~ to the root directory